# Optimising accuracy for OneClassSVM

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a problem which requires the use of a one class classification system. I am currently using python for development and I am using sci-kit learn for machine learning tasks as a result.

From their documentation, the OneClassSVM should be able to work as one would expect (supply positive examples only for training), but the resultant model is  giving me *highly* inaccurate results - even on the original training data.

```
X = generate_data()  # Generate matrix of tf-idf document vectors

cls = OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1, nu=0.1)
cls.fit(X)

y = cls.predict(X)
print y[y == 1].size / y.size
```

The above (simplified) code snippet returns an accuracy score of 40-55% on the *training data*. It performs much much worse on novel data (as one would expect) with almost all results being incorrect.

An accuracy of 40-55% is essentially as good as a random classifier, so what am I doing wrong? I have attempted to play around with the parameters *gamma* and *nu*, but this does not seem to have done much for me.

I am aware that the OneClassSVM implementation makes use of the techniques proposed by Scholkopf et. al and an alternative is the *Support Vector Data Description* technique (Tax and Duin) but this is not implemented within scikitlearn and would require me implementing the interface for libsvm myself. On top of this, from what I understand SVDDs are just about as accurate as the OneClassSVM implementation so there is the potential of not solving my problem at all.

The training data being generated is a matrix of documents represented by standard tf-idf.

Comment: Your data may be extremely high dimensional (judging by your comment on it being tf-idf data). A Gaussian kernel often doesn't work well in that setting.

Comment: It is indeed very high dimensional. What alternatives (if any) should I consider in this case?

Comment: using a linear kernel does indeed improve performance but it is still far away from being as good as when testing on binary classification tasks. Is this just an inherent problem with one class classification?

Comment: Using a linear kernel in this case (where probably `n_samples < n_features`) is also problematic, since most probably every sample will be involved in the decision boundary and it still won't be enough to have the delineated distribution support be compact. Is there no way you can frame this as a classification problem, against some other class?

Comment: Unfortunately its not a simple case, generating a good set of representative negative data is quite difficult in my scenario. This is not to say I *cant* generate negative data, just that there is so much negative data that it is impossible to generate enough to truly represent the negative instance space.

Comment: The Wikipedia page [PU learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PU_learning) lists some literature that might be interesting. Bing Liu's book in particular shows how to adapt off-the-shelf classifiers, like the ones in scikit-learn, to the one-class problem.

Comment: Will give PU learning a look. I'm also trying out some clustering techniques which intuitively should work.

Comment: Try to use the `linear` kernel instead or implement a cross validation that tries out every nu/gamma/kernel combination. Worked much better in my case.